# sd spi mode in C language

Tags: c

can i know how can we send data from spi to micro sd card in 'C' language

Answer (score 2):

This page has some good information on MMC and SD cards, along with a link to a "nice breakdown of the SD SPI protocol".

http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=136

Answer (score 0):

For FAT filesystems, you can find some C code from Microchip [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en537999), as part of the Microchip Application Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Microchip microcontroller, Microchip has a set of libraries that include a library that allows access to a MMC / SD card.

it is called Memory Disk Drive (MDD) and can be found [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784). It works with 8 to 32 bits microcontrollers.